# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "formación" y "capacitación"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario, uso-de-palabras

Estoy escribiendo con mi amiga de Argentina, y ella me habló de su nuevo trabajo.  Ella dijo que tenía que tomar un curso de capacitación, pero veo la palabra "formación" en lugar a veces.

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "formación" y "capacitación"?

Comment: Hay otra diferencia: puedes tener **formación** de médico (conocimientos), pero no estar **capacitado** para ejercerla, por problemas de diversa índole..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pueden ser sinónimos, pero hay diferencia de matiz.

"Formación" es más amplio, y se emplea para la educación en general. "Capacitación" suele usarse en sentido más restringido, para un entrenamiento o curso orientado a una actividad específica.

"Formación" apunta más a lo cultural o intelectual; "capacitación", a lo técnico o laboral.

"Formación" suele estar más relacionado con la teoría, "capacitación" con la práctica (repito:  la diferencia no es tajante, es sólo un matiz).

La "formación" suele implicar mucho tiempo: años de estudio ("educación"), o al menos de actividad que aporta experiencia; la "capacitación" suele aludir a una instrucción preliminar, acotada, destinada a desarrollar una tarea concreta.

Comment: Es España la palabra "capacitación" no se usa al menos de forma habitual, aunque sí se usa en forma de adjetivo: alguien es capaz o alguien está capacitado. Aunque hay alternativas como nombre como "formación", "preparación", "instrucción"... Quizás la diferencia que apuntas en España sería formación / formación técnica.

Comment: Un poco compleja la respuesta ya que en realidad los sinónimos absolutos no existen, y depende de la región para que la gente use una u otra palabra para describir algo.

Comment: @Juanillo No estoy de acuerdo. Sí se usa para los cursillos que te capacitan para ejercer determinada actividad o profesión. Por ejemplo: un curso de que te permitirta ejercer legalmente como electricista será un curso de capacitación laboral.

Comment: Uf, acabo de darme cuenta de que contesto un comentario de hace casi dos años :D

Answer (score 4):

Según mi experiencia, ambas significan lo mismo. Formación se usa preferiblemente en España, mientras que capacitación es usada en Latinoamérica.

Por ejemplo, en mi contexto profesional: vendemos software para empresas y ofrecemos formación postventa a los usuarios para que sepan usarlo. Cuando vendemos en Latinoamérica le llamamos capacitación, pero en España le llamamos formación.

Answer (score 2):

"Formacion" refers to GENERAL "formation" or education.

"Capacitation" refers to giving "capacity" in one specific area, such as art, athletics, maths, mechanics, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Desde mi punto de vista la capacitación es la adquisición de conocimientos técnicos y específicos que se puede realizar en un corto plazo a través de un curso o taller, y la formación es capacitación más entrenamiento, esto significa que conlleva un plazo mayor, más compromiso y mucho más acción con lo que estamos aprendiendo, para dar forma o transformar nuestro ser, adquirimos conocimientos o competencias más genéricas.

Puntualmente observo como principales diferencias:

1. el tiempo: menor en capacitación, mayor en formación.
2. el compromiso: es más profundo el compromiso en la formación ya que hay que estar dispuesto a aceptar una nueva forma.
3. la acción: simultaneidad entre conocer-hacer, pongo en práctica los conocimientos a través del entrenamiento.

Answer (score 2):

Estimo que la expresión `capacitación` se refiere a un proceso de adquisición o transmisión de conocimientos por un período relativamente corto para un aprendizaje, actualización, comprensión o conocimiento en algo concreto para ejercer el trabajo que realizas o vas a realizar.

`Formación`, sea en América Latina y el Caribe como en Europa, se emplea para comprender un programa de estudio pre o posgrado que implica varios años y para el cual la persona que lo recibe está capacitada y apta para desarrollarlo con éxito si pone de sí compromiso, responsabilidad, tenacidad, paciencia y dedicación responsable y estable. No se forma a nadie en varios días, ni semanas. Se requiere de un tiempo mayor de un año y sistematicidad coherente con el objetivo planteado.

Answer (score 1):

Según mi criterio, son dos palabras que se refieren a estudios pero no se correlacionan, así `capacitación` se refiere en un tema en específico y de corta duración, pero `formación` sería de una carrera de pregrado o postgrado que conlleva uno o varios años la formación.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that this question has been protected makes me hesitate to answer, but I had been wondering the same thing myself and before visiting this page, I noticed that the two words seem to be used pretty interchangeably despite the nuances mentioned here in this thread.  Let me start off by sharing with you some of my observations with regard to frequency.  Simply put, in both newspapers and books, **"formación" appears to be much more common than "capacitación."**  Below is an image of Google's Ngram Viewer and its chart of frequency for "formación" and "capacitación" as generated from its database of books:

[image]

Of the two words, **"capacitación" appears to be a "younger" word** — according to the Google Ngram viewer, it doesn't appear until 1778 whereas "formación" appears to have been present in the Spanish language from as far back as 1570.  However, if you consult the [Corpus Diacrónico del Español (CORDE)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpus_Diacr%C3%B3nico_del_Espa%C3%B1ol), it appears that ["formación" can be found as far back as 1455](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll).

As for regional differences, I don't want to tread on anything others have mentioned, but according to what I found at [educalingo.com](https://educalingo.com), it looks as if **["capacitación"](https://educalingo.com/en/dic-es/capacitacion) might be more commonly used in Latin America and ["formación"](https://educalingo.com/en/dic-es/formacion) more commonly used in Spain.**

Interestingly enough, **the [Royal Spanish Academy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Spanish_Academy) lists five different meanings for "formación,"** but none of them are specifically dedicated to "training."  In fact, I don't see any that specifically and directly refer to "training."

[image]

But, its use as a word to mean "training" looks relatively recent and maybe nobody has been breathing down the Academy's neck to get this shade of meaning added.  I suppose something like this trumps the gender battles so many institutions are facing today.  Regardless, to more fully clarify my observations with regard to "formación," I don't really see it used to mean "training," in its modern day sense, until the 1970s.  To be more specific, one of the first instances I see of "formación" used as a word to mean "training" is in the book [*Formación profesional para la mujer*](https://books.google.com/books?id=jr8QAAAAYAAJ&q=%22formaci%C3%B3n%22&dq=%22formaci%C3%B3n%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwih04Dnz4vgAhUhWN8KHfYXDzwQ6AEIVDAG), which was published in 1976.

As for **"capacitación,"** [image]
*Capacitar means to "prepare" or "qualify."*

the Academy only lists one meaning for this word and while it doesn't specifically refer to training either, its definition certainly corresponds more with that word than the five provided for "formación."  The first instances I see of it are right before the turn of the 19th century.  Examples I've seen refer to specific types of training such as scientific or agricultural, which supports what has been said by some in this thread, but I see examples of where "capacitación" is used more broadly as well. Here are a couple of examples:

> **Se cree importante conocer de los propios participantes sus necesidades y preferencias en capacitación.**
> —[*Impacto de los cursos de capacitación en jóvenes desocupados,*](https://books.google.com/books?id=LJJEAAAAYAAJ&q=%22capacitaci%C3%B3n%22&dq=%22capacitaci%C3%B3n%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiogsSX2YvgAhVOPN8KHcOiCwo4ChDoAQhIMAY) Alfonso Uribe
>
> **La capacitación en la empresa es uno de los componentes principales de la inversión de un país en capital humano.**
> —[*Efectos de la Capacitación en la Competitividad de la Industria
> Manufacturera,*](https://books.google.com/books?id=V1EWwtH3mREC&pg=PA13&dq=%22capacitaci%C3%B3n%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjn3Kj02ovgAhXthOAKHfzSB2AQ6AEIMjAB#v=onepage&q=%22capacitaci%C3%B3n%22&f=false)
> United Nations

Nevertheless, a case could be made that both of these examples could be referring to specific types of training of short duration, a meaning for "capacitación" that has already been suggested in this thread and one that helps a student of Spanish determine whether or not to use "capacitación" or "formación."  Even so, students of the Spanish language should be aware that this may be a distinction not all native Spanish speakers may be aware of, or even consider something one must adhere to and, consequently, you may hear or see "formación" used to refer to training of limited or short duration.

---

Keep in mind that there is another word for training — **entrenamiento.**  This word, however, is typically reserved for some type of **physical training** such as "strength training" or "weight training."  It is also the word you would use for "overtraining."